# Clearing lightbox is not in foundation 6 so what is the alternative?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I would like to update my site from foundation 5 to 6, but I notice the clearing lightbox is gone from 6.  I use it for my online albums.  Is there an alternative or a solution provided?

Answer (score 2):

Clearing will be a component that is added in Sites 6.2 - You can see the roadmap for it here: https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/7759

Comment: 6.3 is out, but I still don't see Clearing

Comment: 6.4 is out, and still no word on Clearing :-(

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the trend is to use orbit and reveal together in some kind of pattern as a replacement but it is now being discussed for F7.

https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/issues/7823